# Gerund and its meaning in the sentence, being positioned at the end of the sentence

Tags: prepositions, gerunds, ellipsis

I came across this sentence while watching a video on YouTube.

> They learn to read and write the formal English of textbooks, but get very little training **listening** to - and speaking - causal, conversational, spoken English.
>   <sub>Source: [Get Fluent With 1 Trick - Become A Confident English Speaker With This Simple Practice Trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=l96V7dQtq9E#t=114)</sub> 
>   <sup>(By EnglishAnyone on YouTube; emphasis added)</sup>

What puzzles me here is what sort of connection exists between "get very little training " and "listening". Is there a meaning as in " ...get very little training **in** listening to..."?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the video and the approximate time in the video that the statement occurs?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l96V7dQtq9E  1:58

Answer (score 1):

If you listen to the way he says it (and the emphasis he uses) it is saying that English learners  don't get the experience of listening to spoken English. Personally, I wouldn't use training, rather experience because experience sounds like you are learning at your own pace, and training sounds like a routine.

I can see why you're confused, and you are correct: you can say **get very little training in listening to**...

Comment: So what he did in the sentence by not adding "in", should be considered as incorrect ,right?

Comment: No. You can say both.